# Copying every other element from one array to another in pointer notation

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, char

I'm making a function copy that will copy every other element from *source to *destination to a given numChars. So if source is Hello, and num chars is 2 destination will be "Hl". However the loop runs even after passing numChars, so if source is "Hello There", destination ends up being "HloTee" regardless of what numChars is set to. Any ideas?

```
void copyWord(char * destination, const char * source, int numChars) {
    while (*destination != '\0' && destination < numChars + destination){
        if (*source) {
            *destination = *source;
            source += 2;
            destination++;
        }
        else {
            destination++;
            *destination = '\0';
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you explain a case where you believe `destination<numChars+destination` will be false? What happens when `source` is incremented past the terminating zero?

Comment: i thought that destination<numChars+destination will be false when the address of destination passes destination+numchars*4 which will terminate the loop at the correct numchars

Comment: It's basically `1 < 1 + 1`. `destination` is being incremented. If you wish to keep track of the initial value to compare against then you should do that. Keep in mind that you are only copying half of the characters to `destination` and if the loop terminates because of that condition then `destination` will not be properly terminated.

Comment: A careful programmer might also pass in a destination buffer that was zeroed so the first check is also invalid because the loop would never execute. Even a not so careful programmer that passed in an uninitialized destination buffer wouldn't know if there was a 0 in it or not.

Comment: What would be the best way to keep track of that initial value? I am not allowed to declare any variables to initialize that value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This condition will cause some problems.

```c
*destination != '\0' && destination < numChars + destination
```

Checking that destination isn't at the end likely doesn't do what you want. If destination starts out as an empty string, this loop will never run.

So we try changing this to:

```c
*source != '\0' && destination < numChars + destination
```

But because we increment the `source` pointer by two we can skip over trhe null-terminator.

Instead let's use boring old indexes.

```c
    size_t dest_idx = 0;
    size_t src_idx = 0;
    size_t src_len = strlen(source);

    while (src_idx < src_len && dest_idx < numChars) {
        destination[dest_idx] = source[src_idx];
        dest_idx++;
        src_idx += 2;
    }

    destination[dest_idx] = '\0';
```

Having said that... this looks very much like C and not C++ as tagged. If we want to achieve the same in C++ we might use `std::copy_if` and pass it a lambda which captures a `std::size_t` index variable.

```cpp
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <iostream>

void copyWord(std::string &dest, const std::string &src, std::size_t nun_chars) {
    std::size_t i = 0;

    std::copy_if(
      src.cbegin(), src.cend(),
      std::back_inserter(dest),
      [&i](auto ch){ return i++ % 2 == 0; }
    );
}

int main() {
    std::string src = "hello";
    std::string dest;

    copyWord(dest, src, 5);

    std::cout << dest << std::endl;
}
```

If you're really restricted to char arrays and not declaring more variables, then you need to increment your source pointer twice, but check in between that it hasn't hit the null terminator.

```c
#include <stdio.h>

void copy_word(char *dest, const char *src, size_t num_chars) {
    while (num_chars > 0 && *src) {
        *dest++ = *src++;
     
        if (*src == '\0') break;

        src++;
        num_chars--;
    }

    *dest = '\0';
}
```

Comment: It's C++, just with arbitrary restrictions set by the instructor haha. The reason I set it up the way I did is that we are not allowed to declare any local variables or use any function calls.

Comment: Good call! Thanks. Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

// Be careful that you don't attempt to read from beyond the length of source.
// We assume that dest is large enough to contain substrings of src.

```
#include <cstring>

void copy_word(char *dest, char *src, int numChars) {
    char *p {src};   // Forward pointer to src.
    size_t slen {strlen(src)};   // Determine length of src.

    while (numChars > 0 && p - src < slen) {
         *dest++ = *p;
         p += 2;
         --numChars;
    }
    *dest = 0x00;   // Terminate destination string properly.
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).